# Why is the function $f(x) = \frac{\pi - x}{2}$ odd on $[0, 2 \pi)$?

Tags: real-analysis

My teacher wrote that the function $$f(x)=\frac{\pi - x}{2}$$ is odd on $[0, 2 \pi)$, but this seems false to me. First of all $f(0) \not = 0$ and $f(-x) \not = - f(x)$. How can it be odd?

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. Your teacher probably meant that it has 2-fold rotational symmetry about the point $(\pi,0)$.

Comment: It is so odd ! :D

Comment: $f(-x) $ doesn't even exist your teacher probably meant that the the graph is "odd" when shifted by $\pi$

Comment: The $2\pi$-periodic extension of that function [changed so that $f(0) = 0$] is odd. Hence its Fourier series consists only of sine terms.

Comment: Because the original problem defines $f(0) = \pi/2$, the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function is strictly not an odd function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what your teacher said should be interpreted this way: that the function is odd with respect to the midpoint of the interval, which is $\pi$.

You have $f(\pi)=0$ and for every $\pi - \varepsilon \in [0, \pi$ ] you have $f(\pi - \varepsilon)=\dfrac {\pi - (\pi - \varepsilon))}{2}=\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $f(\pi + \varepsilon)=\dfrac{-\varepsilon} {2}=-f(\pi - \varepsilon)$ and $\pi - \varepsilon$ and $\pi + \varepsilon$ are symmetric with respect to the point $\pi$ just as $x$ and $-x$ are with respect to $0$.